# Using list while mapping it in in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am new to Elixir programming, so i tried to solve some problems from Project Euler, but have a problem with [7th problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7).

I solved the task but the code below is ***too slow***.

```
Stream.iterate(2, &(&1 + 1))
|> Stream.filter(fn x -> Stream.find(2..x, fn y -> rem(x, y) == 0 end) == nil end)
|> Enum.take(10_001)
```

I want to read the current list while processing, because it's **10 times faster**!

In imperative programming languages like Rust, I can do this:

```rust
    let mut list = vec![2];
    let mut i = 2;
    let mut is_prime: bool;

    while list.len() != n {
        i += 1;
        is_prime = true;

        for j in &list {
            if i % j == 0 {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if is_prime {
            list.push(i);
        }
    }
```

When i tried to solve [10th problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10), i wrote this code:

```
list = []

for i <- 2..(2_000_000 - 1) do
  if Enum.find(list, fn x -> rem(x, i) == 0 end) == nil do
    list = list ++ [i]
  end
end

Enum.sum(list) |> IO.puts()
```

But i got this message:

```
warning: variable "list" is unused (there is a variable with the same name in the context, use the pin operator (^) to match on it or prefix this variable with underscore if it is not meant to be used)
```

I expected the list to be updated but I can't even access it.

How can I solve these problems with my method in Elixir?

Comment: Like said by GavinBrelstaff, these are two very different questions. But the second one is easy: you did not update the outer variable "list" but an internal variable shadowing the outer one (that's why the compiler warned). (Also, when you use a for loop in Elixir, it may indicate a wrong approach: Elixir do not use it a lot.)

Comment: Well, @bortzmeyer, i gave two different examples to make sure i cover the problem more broadly.
(And i'm new to stackoverflow so i'm confused about two blocks to describe problem)

Comment: There is no need to lie while asking questions here. The code you’ve published as “solving the issue” would have never been compiled, let alone producing a list of 10K values.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, it's works and solves 10th problem, you are just need to change `n` to number.
What about 7th problem - "The important points" part is enough for me. At least, it changed my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what you want (might take time to complete for big `n` values though since it's a quadratic algorithm):

```elixir
Enum.reduce(2..n, [], fn i, acc -> 
  if Enum.any?(acc, fn x -> rem(i, x) == 0 end) do
    acc
  else
    [i | acc]
  end
end) 
|> Enum.reverse()
```

The important points:

- Using [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) which is convenient to build something while accessing it
- Prepending (O(1)) instead of appending (O(n)) to the accumulator, and [reversing](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reverse/1) at the end